# Adding JS to one page

Tags: jquery

What is the best way to add JS script in wordpress and apply it to one page? As I understand, adding it in template is not recommended. My simple JS is:

```
var allStates = $("svg.us > *");

allStates.on("click", function() {

  allStates.removeClass("on");
  $(this).addClass("on");

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new dir and file dedicated to your javascript. `/js/scripts.js`.

Wrap your entire javascript like this:

```
( function( $ ) {

  var allStates = $("svg.us > *");

  allStates.on("click", function() {

    allStates.removeClass("on");
    $(this).addClass("on");

  });

} )( jQuery );
```

Then in your theme's functions file, put this code. It loads your new js file.

```
function your_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'your-script-handle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', false );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_scripts' );
```

That way, all your javascript is available on any page and is loaded only once (afterwards, it's in browser cache). Since your function is `on click` it's fine for it to be available on all pages.

Comment: I would agree this approach is the most efficient way. You could then check to see if a unique class or id exist from your unique page(s), to then execute the javascript.  Centralizing javascript to a single location makes it that much easier to manage as the site continues to grow.

Comment: @cowgill Unfortunately, despite the fact that the script is loaded, it still doesn't work. When I check the code on non-wordpress site, it works normally.

Comment: @Rafal, any error messages in the console window? Can you include the HTML piece of your code above that the JavaScript triggers?

Comment: @cowgill I can't see any errors in the console. JS is trigered by clicking on paths part of the code is `<svg class="us" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="100%"
  height="500px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" enable-background="new 0 0 200 200" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="south">
 <a href="#southten" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta"><path clip-rule="evenodd" d=" .... " "/></a>
</g>`

Answer (score 1):

Check your page with [`is_page`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) in [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) just in time for [`wp_add_inline_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/).

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {

    if ( is_page( 'your-page-name' ) ) : ob_start(); ?>

        // generic    
        alert('Custom JS Loaded!');

        // custom           
        var allStates = $("svg.us > *");

        allStates.on("click", function() {

        allStates.removeClass("on");
        $(this).addClass("on");

        });
        <?php wp_add_inline_script( 'jquery-migrate', sprintf( '( function( $ ) { %s } )( jQuery );', ob_get_clean() ) );

    endif; // test page

} );
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the following to check for a page before enqueuing. You may need to update your login inside the if statement if the post type is not a page - that this is the general concept:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', 'enqueue_my_script');
function enqueue_my_script() {
    $page_title = 'Page Title';
    if ( is_page( $page_title ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'your-script-handle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', false );
    }
}
```